# I want to get a single column from the table in the database according to the given condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I want to get a single column from my table related to my `GetValue` method in my base class according to the condition I will give. A single value will be returned.

For example: I want to return the `OrganizationItemName` column of the `OrganizationItemID = 4` from my `OrganizationItem` table. With EF Core, I use:

```
MyResult = _context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(mystr).ToString();
```

I get a http 404 - not found error in the API because an entity freezes back when I do it.

But when I do as follows, I get the result I want. I'm trying to find a way how I can do this with EF Core. Anyone have any ideas?

```
public string? GetValue(string TableName, string ColumnName, string SQLCriteria)
{
    string? MyResult = "";

    string mystr = $"SELECT {ColumnName} FROM {TableName} WHERE {SQLCriteria}";
    FormattableString query = $"SELECT {ColumnName} FROM {TableName} WHERE {SQLCriteria}";

    try
    {
        // MyResult = _context.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(mystr).ToString();

        using (var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = mystr;
            _context.Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (result.Read())
                {
                    MyResult = result[ColumnName]?.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return MyResult;
}
```

Comment: Why not just use standard EF to compose the SQL:`var result = _context.OrganizationItem .Where (e => e.OrganizationItemID == 4).Select(e => e.OrganizationItemName).FirstOrDefault();`. If you must use raw SQL and are using EF 7 then you can use [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types), e.g.  `_context.Database.SqlQuery<string>(mystr).FirstOrDefault()`, but I'd be wary of your method of composing SQL, as noted it is vulnerable to SQL Injection (either malicious or simply just malformed SQL)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a list of data:

```
List<string> nameList = await _contact.OrganizationItems.Where(o => o.OrganizationItemID == 4).Select(o => o.OrganizationItemName).ToListAsync();
```

If you want to get first data, then use one of them:

```
string name = await _contact.OrganizationItems.Where(o => o.OrganizationItemID == 4).Select(o => o.OrganizationItemName).FirstAsync();
string name = await _contact.OrganizationItems.Where(o => o.OrganizationItemID == 4).Select(o => o.OrganizationItemName).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

If the `OrganizationItemID` field is the primary key (and only one record with it is possible):

```
string name = (await _contact.OrganizationItems.FindAsync(4))?.OrganizationItemName;
```

Don't forget to add error checking for null values.

I advise you to study the basic methods of EF Core for data manipulation

P.S. Try not to use the `FromRawSql()` method, because this can lead to SQL injection attacks.

If there is no need to use asynchronous code, then simply remove `await` and `Async` (example: ToListAsync() -> ToList())

Answer (score 0):

Use method `FromSqlRaw` and pass the context explicitly, it cannot be composed over an arbitrary LINQ query ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#basic-sql-queries)).

```
MyResult = _context.Entity.FromSqlRaw(mystr).ToList();
```

Note that this is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.